# Electrician Terminology "FAU"

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

I've noticed these letters several times written on the circuit breaker panel door. Does someone know what F.A.U. stands for in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FAU is likely a "forced air unit" (e.g. a heater or air conditioner).
If it's two breaker switches tied together, that's a 240V volt circuit (if there's no tie between the two switches, that's an immediate hazard and must be fixed).

Comment: Thanks. It is written twice, so as to label a double breaker slot. Would that imply the unit is powered for 220 volts?

Comment: If the breaker handles are tied together so they both operate simultaneously, then yes, it would be a 220/240V circuit.

Comment: Thanks. So if my furnace uses natural gas as a fuel to heat would that mean that the 220 line voltage is for the blower motor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, FAU is "forced air unit", but this term is not used everywhere. Around here you'll many times see AH, or A/H for "air handler", which is what we would call the inside blower unit of a split air conditioning system.

Comment: Thanks. I would think they would want to be more specific so as to identify what the breaker is protecting. (Air Con. or Attic Furnace, etc.). FAU is to general.